# OneDrive API returns invalid_grant for grant_type=refresh_token

Tags: onedrive

I have taken charge of older project base on PHP 5.2 which connects to OneDrive and allows user to send files from the website into his OneDrive folder. The app uses this library: https://github.com/lovattj/php-skydrive

Unfortunatelly, there's an issue which I was not able to find in Microsoft's Docs. When user creates authentification, it works, but a minute later when the app tries to synchronize, it uses refresh token request (function refresh_oauth_token) with data:

```
client_id=xxx
redirect_uri=xxx
client_secret=xxx
refresh_token=xxx
grant_type=refresh_token
```

And it returns following error (not documented)...

> error:"invalid_grant", error_description:"The provided value for the
>   input parameter 'refresh_token' or 'assertion' is not valid."